# Transform this expression in something useful for me

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have $A \subset \Omega$ and $E \subset \Omega$.

Now I have $A\cap E^C$. But I do not want to work with the complement, I am rather looking for an expression that somehow contains $A \cap E$. Does anybody know whether this is possible.

Comment: I'm not clear on what your asking

Comment: I want to transform the expression $A \cap E^C$ in something that contains the expression $A \cap E$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$A\cap E^c=A\setminus E=A\setminus(A\cap E)$$